# I got error with flutter: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)

Tags: flutter

I tried creating a registration page and connecting it to the localhost database. after I input the data, I get an error : flutter: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1) and the data is not saved into the database. I have checked whether the data entered is the same but the results still produce an error :flutter: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)

**this is my code. i hope someone to help me with my problem**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:appproject/pages/main_home.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class RegisterPage extends StatelessWidget {

  RegisterPage({super.key, required String title});

  TextEditingController nama = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController email = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController no_hp = TextEditingController();

  Future<void> insertrecord() async {
    if(nama.text!="" || email.text!="" || password.text!="" ){
      try{
        String uri = "http://192.168.1.5/hp_api/insert_data.php";
        var res = await http.post(Uri.parse(uri), body: {
          "nama": nama.text,
          "email": email.text,
          "password": password.text
        });
        var response=jsonDecode(res.body);
        if(response["success"]=="true"){
          print("Data Berhasil Disimpan");
        }else{
          print("Data Gagal Disimpan");
        }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      }
    }else{
      print("Dimohon Mengisi Semua Data");
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home : Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Register'),
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              children:[
                Container( child: TextFormField(
                  controller: nama,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Nama Lengkap'),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                Container( child: TextFormField(
                  controller: email,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Email'),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                Container( child: TextFormField(
                  controller: password,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Password'),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Register'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    insertrecord();
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const MainHome(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        );
      }
  }
```

I got error flutter: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1), the connection to db is work but that is not insert into db

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in the past when working on my localhost database. The solution was to set the manual proxy configuration of the Android emulator.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWsvG.png

You must write your own localhost address in hostname field.